# Golang Отрисовка текста на изображении с форматиравнием

Tags: изображения, golang, шрифты

Подскажите, есть ли готовые решение для отрисовки текста на изображении в заданном блоке (Rect) с учетом следующих пунктов:

1) Автоматический перенос теста на новую строку (подобие блока текста в word, powerpoint и тд)
2) Выравнивание текста в блоке (Left, Middle, Right)
3) Размеры шрифта и Spacing

Банальная отрисовка текста не совсем то, что нужно. Тот же FreeType все это умеет. Мне интересные именно автоматические вычисления переноса строк и выравнивание. Пока не нашел готовых вариантов.
Если ничего готового нет, то тогда вопрос: подскажите, как удобнее всего это вычислять? Может есть примеры какие?

Comment: Вопрос хороший, но скорее всего ответ будет, что такого нет.  Вёрстка текста — обширная и сложная задача.  Д. Кнут целую диссертацию об этом написал, и так родился [_TeX_](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX).